# SQL Server 2008 - Can you index a persisted column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, persisted-column

Is it possible to index a persisted field?

When trying to change a primary key to a persisted field or 
add a primary key to a field I've made persisted field I get the following:

> Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table
>   'tblOpportunityRecords'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to male your computed field non-null, you need to help SQL Server figure out that no nulls are possible. Usually, this is done using the `ISNULL` function which can be used to ensure that the resulting expression is non-nullable.

```
ISNULL(my_computation, 0) --the second arg should have the same type as the first one
```

Note, that you can't use the `COALESCE` function (for a reason unknown to me - it just doesn't work).

Comment: Interesting - with `ISNULL(...)` the column indeed becomes non-nullable and thus can be used for a primary key. I still wouldn't put my primary key on such a computed column - but it's technically possible. Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "throws"?

Comment: @MartinSmith That phrase was poorly chosen. I've replaced it with "raises an error".

Comment: @usr - That's what I thought you might mean. It doesn't. It is just important that the second parameter is `NOT NULL`-able. `ISNULL(null,null)` doesn't raise an error and creates a nullable column.

Comment: @MartinSmith I did not know that (I repro'd this in reaction to your comment and you're right). Good to know! I fixed my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A primary key **must** be - by definition - `NOT NULL` and unique.

But you *can* index a persisted computed column with a regular non-clustered index - absolutely!

Comment: How can I make the persisted field no nulls as it won't let you change that for persisted fields.  Both the fields it references to create it are NO NULL.

Comment: @aSystemOverload: I don't think there's any way to do this - plus I would never put my primary key onto a persisted column .... use some other good primary key - an `INT IDENTITY` or something - and index your computed column with a suitable non-clustered index!

Comment: I did have it as an INT, but the number of records will increase substantially and MS ACcess which I use as a front end cannot access bigint datafields so thats what led me to consider a persisted field.  The records are repeated historical records, so there is a unique value repeated in each DataSet so I created the persisted field as DataSetID + UNiqueValue, which would be table unique.